# Php Cron job not working, using crontab -e command

Tags: php, cron

i want to set a cron job on a server but its not working. I know there are hundreds of links on web that shows how to setup a cron job but i cant seem to make it work. What im doing now is:
1) Running crontab -e.
Then it shows bunch of lines in the command line.
2) I go to the bottom and add */5 * * * * path/to/myfile.php
and then i exit the editor in command line. Please tell me whats wrong here. Do i need to put my file in a specific folder? or do i need to go to the desired folder and then use crontab -e, or something else. Please forgive me, this is my first cronjob, hoping to be better next time.
Here are the pictures of what im doing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the cron service after you updated the file?

Have you tried executing the php script from the command line first to verify that it's executing as expected?  It might be that the cron task is executing but the script is failing.  If the script is fine, you might want to try using  php as a command followed by the path and filename of the php file and then quitting the execution after it's done with -q.

```
*/5 * * * * php path/to/myfile.php -q
```

Comment: Yeah i've tried the file on localhost, it was working fine..im 100% sure that the file is fine. You said "Did you restart the cron service after you updated the file?" What does that means and how to do it?

Comment: whenever you update a cron file, you need to restart the cron service so that it takes effect. For instance, on ubuntu, after you've saved the file you would type   "service cron restart" to restart the service and have the changes you made take effect.

Comment: hmm i'll do that, just now a thought crossed my mind, the file that im running in a cron job, is in /home/admin/file.php, i mean is it placed right? I mean should i place under /var/www/  or somewhere else?

Comment: also quick question, what is the root directory on a server like htdocs in localhost??

Comment: I would try running under the /var/www/ location and see if that works.  I've done that before with an separate directory for scripts and its worked well.  For your other question, it's going to be base on  what os you're running.

Comment: When i opened the host ip that i was provided on the browser the default page says its a debian system.

Comment: I should say it's a combination of the os distribution and server configuration.  That said, you might want to try looking at the /etc/apache2 directory and find a configuration file.  That conf file would define the Document Root path and other variables that Apache is using to look for documents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could well be that you are trying to execute a PHP file and your system is unaware of what to do with it.

Is your PHP file executable?

You can make it executable by running

```
$ chmod +x file.php
```

and if you add a shebang to it

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

// ...
```

the PHP script can be executed by running

```
$ ./file.php
```

Alternatively, you need to run the PHP interpreter and pass it the path to the file as an argument.

```
$ php file.php
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: I did that, nothing happened.